# Testing Electron app using selenium, javascript in windows

Tags: selenium-webdriver, electron

I have a Windows application developed based on Electron, and I want to use Selenium for automated testing of this application.

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('remote-debugging-port', '9222')
```

I have set up this in the application and tried to connect to the application using a test.js file as following.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
async function test() {
    const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .usingServer('http://localhost:9515')
  .withCapabilities({
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      binary: 'xxx/node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe'
    }
  })
  .forBrowser('chrome') // 注意: 使用 .forBrowser('electron') for selenium-webdriver <= 3.6.0
  .build()
driver.get('http://localhost:9222')
}
test()
```

However, I can only receive inspect page .I can click one link to control my application page. but i am unable to access the internal elements of the application by coding.
[image]
If I use this URL to access the application (my main process loads the renderer process through this URL),

```
driver.get('http://localhost:9080')
```

it shows a blank screen and i can't see any error in bash. (I can't open devtools),How can I open the devtools to see error during loading http://localhost:9080.

How can I perform automated testing of my application using Selenium?